# How do I set maxHeight inside AccordionDetails and make it scrollable?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have 100's of data to show using Accordion (material-ui) inside a Box component, but not sure how to manipulate the built in styles to set the maxHeight. Is there a way that I can control the styles instead of showing all movies when the dropdown is clicked?

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-c3v8ip?file=/src/App.tsx:5794-5810)

Comment: please share your code with sandbox. which material version are you using? please share what you have tried?

Comment: @LakruwanPathirage The sandbox link is in the question (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-c3v8ip?file=/src/App.tsx:5794-5810)

Comment: can you share image that explaining what you need? I didn't understand your question

Comment: In the sandbox link, when you click on Movies, you might see plenty of movies loaded up. What I'm trying here is to set the maxHeight for the         <AccordionDetails> so I can show data up to the maxHeight I specified and the rest make it scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the answer with sandbox.[url](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordian-dsqvcp?file=/src/App.tsx)
I have used sx prop and overflowy to scroll.

Answer (score 4):

Add this style in your css file and make height according your requirement, it works!

```
.MuiAccordionDetails-root {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-pc3udc?file=/src/styles.css:59-132

Comment: Sweet. Can we make this using sx prop?

Comment: Yeah. I think I figured out Priyen. Thanks a ton mate :)

<AccordionDetails sx={{ maxHeight: "300px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>

Comment: Yeah, I also did that please accept my answer and do upvote thanks :)

Comment: is there anyway to use variable height using %

Comment: Yes, You can use in percentage as well like this: ex: max-height: 40%;

Answer (score 0):

I used the sx prop to achieve the desired result. Check out the following code:

```
<AccordionDetails sx={{ display: 'flex', maxHeight: "50vh",overflowY: "scroll"}}
{someList}
</AccordionDetails>
```

[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhdh.png)